# How to redirect remote image url to local folder in development?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, express, reverse-proxy

I am fetching the image urls from database (dump from production server).
For example, say - *https://example.com/imageStorage/photo.jpg* is an url fetched from database.
And these urls are used to show images in HTML templates like this -

```
<img [src]="url">
```

Now in development i want to redirect these urls to fetch images from a local folder. I am using NodeJS express and angular in my application. Is there any way to do it. I tried to proxy the requests with no success.

Comment: Have you tried using a HttpInterceptor and returning the bas64/array buffer of the local asset instead of making the request? https://angular.io/guide/http#write-an-interceptor

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was thinking about doing it. But is it possible with proxy ?

Comment: Why not just replacing base url with localhost?

Comment: @MiladRaeisi Because, As I mentioned in the post these URLs are fetched from database dumps of production server.

Comment: you can intercept network request and change them
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests

Comment: @MiladRaeisi in my case i need to modify the response not request. The urls i get from server is through the response. Now i need to modify the responses to point to local folder, let's say response have an url https://example.com/imageStorage/imageName.ext, now i need to change it to http://localhost:3000/imageStorage/imageName.ext. Since the responses are complex and these url's are in nested arrays, i am looking for a way to forward all these request to local server instead of modifying the response.

Comment: I still think you should try to use a HttpInterceptor. This is an ideal solution to your specific use case. HttpInterceptors can intercept requests and/or responses client side, so you can implement any custom logic you choose changing the request url to point to your node server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en

and then add a url redirect like this

[image: modHeader extension example]

Comment: Thanks for the response but I cannot install any extension, it is blocked by Admin. I already know about these extensions and I use them on my laptop. I am looking for a way to proxy the requests without any third party software or extension. I am trying the interceptors as suggested by @bjlasc01